# Changing default font to charter in memoir

Tags: fonts, memoir

I have been trying to change the default font from `lmodern` to `charter` in `memoir` class, but the output does not change.

I used

```
\newcommand*{\memfontfamily}{bch}
\newcommand*{\memfontenc}{T1}
\newcommand*{\memfontpack}{charter}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
```

as suggested in the manual (pg. 3 + 38).

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

This complicated setup is necessary only if the `extrafontsizes` option is desired.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
```

will do.